# CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException when integration with MarmaladeSDK and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, marmalade

I tried to use Crashlytics instead of FirebaseCrash Reporting. I added all relevant Libraries: crashlytics, fabric, answer, beta and everything compiled and started properly on my Android device. I'm working with MarmaladeSDK which has no AndroidStudio/gradle integration. I need to add every lib by myself to the build system (jars, Android Manifest, Resources mainly).

I have two issues:

1. Crashlytics is not started automatically. I had to call 
   `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` Which aar library is reponsible for starting the crashlytics services?
2. I got an `CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException` with the error message:

   ```
   This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at 
   https://fabric.io/sign_up, install an Android build tool and ask a team 
   member to invite you to this app's organization.
   ```

How does chrashlytics gets the knowledge that Firebase is the new destination and that there is no need to register at the fabric.io website?

I have no idea what `apply plugin:'io.fabric'` does? Can I mimic this behaviour even without Android studio? My main issue is probably that gradle does some magic which I don't understand and I assume that `apply plugin:'io.fabric'` could be responsible for that.